# Cant get root password chrome os

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-os

I recently got a new Chromebook [used] and I cant get the root password because I don't know it, I want to be able to boot Linux but I can't without use of sudo, How to fix?

Answer (score 1):

sudo passwd root, this will allow you to set the root password

Comment: Anything with sudo infront of it needs the password which I don't know

Comment: if you are logged in, the password it asks you for is the one for the current logged in user

Comment: after that it will have you reset the root user password

Comment: Are you logging in? or is it automatic login? what should happen is this. Open terminal. Type sudo passwd root, it should ask for the current logged in password, after that it should prompt for "new Unix password" you answer this twice and that should be it, please explain where this is changing from what I have wrote.

Comment: Another thing you can try but I don;t know   if chrome uses this. type in sudo su, it should ask for the password to the logged in user and drop to a root prompt

Answer (score 0):

I had been having this problem for forever, and finally after searching found the answer in a thread on github.
You have to do a reset of your computer, go to the sign in page and do ctrl-alt-shift- letter R
Go into developer mode and then when it asks you to enable debugging, DO NOT ENABLE DEBUGGING!!
Enabling debugging is what creates the password problem. I hope this helps.